# Syntax Error in VBA SQL ACCDB execution expected 'DELETE','INSERT','SELECT,'PROCEDURE', or 'UPDATE'

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I want to make a button to count actions in Outlook.

I have the following code, but unfortunately it's not working:

```
Dim conn As ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Set conn = New ADODB.Connection

conn.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=P:\UHD-GEOBAN\SPOC und Incident\Screenshots\Sven\VBA\statistik.accdb; Persist Security Info=False;"
conn.Open
'DB: ID; currentDate; spocmail; onlinebankingmail
conn.Execute ("IF (NOT EXISTS(select * from tbl_statistics WHERE currentDate = '" & Date & "'))BEGIN INSERT INTO tbl_statistics(currentDate, spocmail) VALUES('" & Date & "', '1') END ELSE BEGIN UPDATE tbl_statistics SET spocmail = spocmail + 1 WHERE currentDate = '" & Date & "' END")
```

I also would like to know, if it's possible to put the long SQL statements in multiple lines in the VBA code

Thanks in forward

Comment: I can't help you with your main question but the also yes. You can split the code using "& _" as line break, without the quotes.

Comment: Thanks for your fast reply. This works for "normal" VBA code, but i cannot use "& _" or " _" as a line brake in the SQL statement itself, as the code turns red and i get a simple "syntax error"

Comment: I believe it's because you are passing a string, so when you split the string you need to end the string and start it again every line break.

Comment: Did you try to run the SQL statement in your database? I think this is not valid SQL code for a Access database but I am not sure.

Comment: I agree IF/ELSE/BEGIN/END look more like T-SQL, there are no such constructs in Access SQL

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim conn As ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Set conn = New ADODB.Connection

conn.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=P:\UHD-GEOBAN\SPOC und Incident\Screenshots\Sven\VBA\statistik.accdb; Persist Security Info=False;"
conn.Open
set rs = new ADODB.Recordset
rs.open "Select * from tbl_statistics where currentdate = #" & format(date(),"dd mmm yyyy") & "#" ,conn
'unless you're in the US not specifying the date format will bite you
if rs.eof then 
     conn.execute "INSERT INTO tbl_statistics(currentDate, spocmail) VALUES('#" & format(Date,"dd mmm yyyy")  & "#', '1') 

else
   conn.execute "UPDATE tbl_statistics SET spocmail = spocmail + 1 WHERE currentDate = '#" & format(Date,"dd mmm yyyy" & "#"
end if
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, unfortunately this does not seem to work :/

Comment: where does it error? I don't have the tables so I can't test any of it - I may have made a syntax error

Comment: nevermind - it is working now. I have declared "currentDate" in the database as date, but with text it works now